# Kivy dropdown: can you make it drop "up" instead of "down"?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a UI in Kivy with a load of buttons at the bottom of the screen. Ideally I want some of these buttons to be dropdowns but of course since they are at the bottom of the screen, you can't see the dropdown when they are tapped.

Is there any way to display dropdown items up rather than down?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [kivy-md library](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) if you start the application by running the `main.py` you will be able to see a demonstration of the up opening dropdown button. The widget is called `MDRaisedButton`.

Here is a preview

[image]